# ValueError when trying to use acf_plot from Statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, statsmodels

I have the following dataframe 'data' :

| **Month** | Revenue Index |
| --- | --- |
| **1920-01-01** | 1.72 |
| **1920-02-01** | 1.83 |
| **1920-03-01** | 1.94 |
| **...** | ... |
| **2021-10-01** | 114.20 |
| **2021-11-01** | 115.94 |
| **2021-12-01** | 116.01 |

I am trying to draw differencing plots and ACF plots since it is a time series. I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex=True)
axes[0, 0].plot(data['Revenue Index']); axes[0, 0].set_title('Original Series')
plot_acf(data['Revenue Index'], ax=axes[0, 1])

axes[1, 0].plot(data['Revenue Index'].diff()); axes[1, 0].set_title('1st Order Differencing')
plot_acf(data['Revenue Index'].diff().dropna(), ax=axes[1, 1])

axes[2, 0].plot(data['Revenue Index'].diff().diff()); axes[2, 0].set_title('2nd Order Differencing')
plot_acf(data['Revenue Index'].diff().diff().dropna(), ax=axes[2, 1])

plt.show()
```

And the output of this code should look like this:

[image]

But unfortunately I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d4f41541459e> in <module>()
      9 plot_acf(df['Consumptieprijsindex'].diff().diff().dropna(), ax=axes[2, 1])
     10 
---> 11 plt.show()

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in viewlim_to_dt(self)
   1096                              'often happens if you pass a non-datetime '
   1097                              'value to an axis that has datetime units'
-> 1098                              .format(vmin))
   1099         return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
   1100 

ValueError: view limit minimum -36906.25 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

The Month column is already set as Index and it is DateTime format. It is good to mention that some monthly values are missing during WW2, I don't know if that is the reason why I get this error.

Does somebody know why my code is not working? Thanks!

Comment: It's not reproducible. `df.Month = pd.to_datetime(df.Month).dt.date`

Comment: If you continue to experience the issue. then update `pandas`, and `matplotlib`.